# Serialize Java Library for Spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, serialization

i'm using Spark to run a script in scala. I'm using [PrettyTime][1] as a library. However it is not serializable.

```html
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:298)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2094)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:370)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:369)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:369)
at lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:74)
at lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:84)
at lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:86)
at lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:88)
at lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:90)
at lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:92)
at lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:94)
at lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:96)
at lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:98)
at lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:100)
at lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:102)
at lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:104)
at lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:106)
at lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:108)
at lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:110)
at lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:112)
at lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:114)
at lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:116)
at lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
at lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$DateTimeParser$
Serialization stack:
- object not serializable (class: lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$DateTimeParser$, value: lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$DateTimeParser$@3b72e48)
- field (class: lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: DateTimeParser$module, type: class lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$DateTimeParser$)
- object (class lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw@2546ce7c)
- field (class: lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: $iw, type: class lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw)
- object (class lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw@1e837893)
- field (class: lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: $iw, type: class lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw)
- object (class lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw@5fc3c9ba)
- field (class: lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: $iw, type: class lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw)
- object (class lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw@2974b4ab)
- field (class: lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: $iw, type: class lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw)
- object (class lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw@6f1669ab)
- field (class: lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: $iw, type: class lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw)
- object (class lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw@5617a000)
- field (class: lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: $iw, type: class lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw)
- object (class lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw@18ccefe9)
- field (class: lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: $iw, type: class lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw)
- object (class lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw@784ba0ac)
- field (class: lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: $iw, type: class lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw)
- object (class lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw@4c399f7d)
- field (class: lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: $iw, type: class lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw)
- object (class lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw@4a43d546)
- field (class: lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: $iw, type: class lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw)
- object (class lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw@78821701)
- field (class: lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: $iw, type: class lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw)
- object (class lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw@6eb07bcc)
- field (class: lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: $iw, type: class lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw)
- object (class lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw@59a7cec1)
- field (class: lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: $iw, type: class lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw)
- object (class lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw, lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw@7b8fc596)
- field (class: lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw, name: $iw, type: class lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw)
- object (class lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw, lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw@6974a1eb)
- field (class: lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw, name: $iw, type: class lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw$$iw)
- object (class lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw, lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw@7288ec90)
- field (class: lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read, name: $iw, type: class lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read$$iw)
- object (class lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read, lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read@3a8befaa)
- field (class: lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495$read, type: class lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f5495.$read)
- object (class lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw@3d361fe7)
- field (class: lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: $outer, type: class lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw)
- object (class lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw@241effb0)
- field (class: lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$2, name: $outer, type: class lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw)
- object (class lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$2, <function1>)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:295)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2094)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:370)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:369)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:369)
at lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:74)
at lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:84)
at lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:86)
at lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:88)
at lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:90)
at lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:92)
at lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:94)
at lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:96)
at lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:98)
at lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:100)
at lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:102)
at lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:104)
at lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:106)
at lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:108)
at lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:110)
at lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:112)
at lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:114)
at lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:116)
at lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
at lineb8a1770bfabb4ce4a0bcef2d50888f54105.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
```

I tried this idea [here](https://www.nicolaferraro.me/2016/02/22/using-non-serializable-objects-in-apache-spark/), to create an object wrapper but it still doesn't work.

Any ideas? My code:

```html
object Holder {
  def pretty() = {
    val prettyTime = new PrettyTimeParser()
    prettyTime
  }
}

object DateTimeParser {

  val NameMask = "DATETIME"

  case class dateParts(times: scala.collection.immutable.List[Date], text: String, line: Int, position: Int)

  def apply(emailBody: String): Seq[dateParts] = parseEmail(emailBody)

  def normalizeBody(emailBody: String): String = {
    val dates: Seq[dateParts] = parseEmail(emailBody)
    val dateStrings: Seq[String] = dates map (_.text)
    val dateMap: Map[String, String] = dateStrings.map((_, NameMask)).toMap

    dateMap.foldLeft(emailBody) { case (cur, (regex, _)) => cur.replaceAll(regex, NameMask) }
  }

  def parseEmail(emailBody: String): Seq[dateParts] = {
    val parsed: Seq[DateGroup] = Holder.pretty.parseSyntax(emailBody).asScala.toList
    parsed
      .map(curr => dateParts(curr.getDates.asScala.toList, curr.getText, curr.getLine, curr.getPosition))
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7GoP.png)

Comment: Please show your Spark codes

Comment: @zsxwing, I'm running via Databricks so what I have attached if all that I'm running currently.

Comment: I don't see the codes calling Spark APIs. Are you sure?

Comment: 100% - databricks has spark built into it (it's a notebooking platform). just added a screenshot

Comment: The screenshot is what I was asking. Could you paste the codes and the whole stack trace in the screenshot here?

Comment: it's too long to post here - I've updated the section above with the full stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An object cannot be serialized if it contains something which is not serializable.

When you have to use a non-`Serializable` class over which you have no control, a possible workaround is to instantiate the class directly within your closure.

```
val normal =
  email.
    ...
    map(body => (body, DateTimeParser.normalizeBody(body, new PrettyTimeParser))).
    ...
```

To minimize object creation, you can create it within a call to `mapPartitions` instead of `map`.

```
val normal =
  email.
    ...
    mapPartitions {
      bodies => 
        lazy val parser = new PrettyTimeParser
        for (body <- bodies) yield
          (body, DateTimeParser.normalizeBody(body, parser)))
    }.
    ...
```

Another way (if the classes runs thread-safe code) can be to create the parser once outside of the closure inner scope, mark it as a `@transient lazy val` and then use it in your closure, so that each executor will create its own.

```
@transient lazy val parser = new PrettyTimeParser

val normal =
  email.
    ...
    map(body => (body, DateTimeParser.normalizeBody(body, parser))).
    ...
```

In every case you'd need to adapt your code so that it takes a parser as an argument:

```
object DateTimeParser {

  val NameMask = "DATETIME"

  case class dateParts(times: scala.collection.immutable.List[Date], text: String, line: Int, position: Int)

  def apply(emailBody: String): Seq[dateParts] = parseEmail(emailBody)

  def normalizeBody(emailBody: String, parser: PrettyTimeParser): String = {
    val dates: Seq[dateParts] = parseEmail(emailBody, parser)
    val dateStrings: Seq[String] = dates map (_.text)
    val dateMap: Map[String, String] = dateStrings.map((_, NameMask)).toMap

    dateMap.foldLeft(emailBody) { case (cur, (regex, _)) => cur.replaceAll(regex, NameMask) }
  }

  def parseEmail(emailBody: String, parser: PrettyTimeParser): Seq[dateParts] = {
    val parsed: Seq[DateGroup] = parser.parseSyntax(emailBody).asScala.toList
    parsed
      .map(curr => dateParts(curr.getDates.asScala.toList, curr.getText, curr.getLine, curr.getPosition))
  }
}
```

Should you encounter other unserializable objects, keep applying the same approach until you make it work.

Comment: So this is very helpful, thank you @stefanobaghino. So it sounds like there is no way to create one instance of PrettyTimeParser and serialize that to multiple nodes? The main reason I wanted to serialize is to improve runtime efficiency (if creating an instance of dateTimeParser takes nontrivial time and computation power)

Comment: I see your point, but unfortunately there is no way around this, if you don't own the library and cannot simply mark it as `Serializable`. Furthermore, in a job working with GBs/TBs/PBs of data, creating a parser for each executor is likely to be not that much of a waste, considering that also serialization has a cost.